# 64k x 8 RAM - what exactly does it mean?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, ram

I'm looking at [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PIC32MX575F512H-80I%2FPT/PIC32MX575F512H-80I%2FPT-ND/2184458) microcontroller because it has the protocols that I want and a really interesting price.
My doubt is related with this field: RAM Size   64K x 8.
What exactly does it mean? I know what it means RAM but 8 blocks. How it works?

Comment: 64KB is a lot of RAM for a microcontroller, I was writing apps that had to make do with 1536 bytes and also 256 bytes in earlier PICS. Are you designing efficient data structures? Check to see if there is an upgrade path, there often is for PICs,develop and debug for that device and if you do run out of RAM, go to the next device up in the family, if there is one. I found the PICs almost unbeatable in terms of peripheral feature set and power consumption.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that the RAM is organised in a structure which is 64K **Words** wide. The x8 then means that each word is 8 bits.

So 32Kx16 would be a RAM which is 32K Words wide, at 16bits per word.

Answer (score 4):

Memory capacity is 2 dimension. Rows and Columns. So, here 64K refers to Rows(Word) and 8 refers to Column (numbers of bits per Word).

[image: Here is an example image of 64K x 16 RAM as an analogy. It is 64K Words wide and each word is 16 bits wide]

For further reading and Image Reference-
http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~moshovos/ECE243-06/l24-synthesizing-larger-memories.html

Answer (score 3):

64 Kilobytes, bytewise.
64K * 8 bits wide.

Comment: 64 [**kibi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)bytes, to be exact.